# Javascript/jquery for many items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using token_input for an autoComplete feature. Until now there was only one item using this autoComplete, so I had this script:

```
$(function() {
  $("#bcl_tag_ids").tokenInput("/admin/tags/filter", {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $("#bcl_tag_ids").data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook"
  });
});
```

Now there will be many of them, so I came with something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".token_input").tokenInput("/admin/tags/filter", {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $(".token_input").data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook"
  });
});
```

Instead of looking for an id now I'm looking for a class, but I don't know how to fix the path `/admin/tags/filter` so it can be dynamically loaded with the proper path, for example `/admin/tags/filter`, `/admin/musics/filter`, `/admin/anythings/filter`.

I could take that part of the path from the `item#id` but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add the path as a custom attribute to your element like

```
<input class="token_input" data-path="/admin/tags/filter"/>
```

Then, you could do something like

```
$(function() {
  $(".token_input").each(function(){
   $(this).tokenInput($(this).attr('data-path'), {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $(this).data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook"
  });
});
```